# How to return time count down in table rows

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have to list of table rows I wish to return time count-down along with other field from angular component, but am finding it difficult to get the count-down to work for each rows in the table.

Here is my component method

```
      getTaskCountdown(task: TaskInterface): Observable<string> {
        return new Observable(observable => {

            let countDown: string;
            const countDownDate: number = new Date(task.end).getTime();
            const x = setInterval(() => {
                const now = new Date().getTime();
                // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                const distance = countDownDate - now;
                const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                const hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                countDown = days + 'd ' + hours + 'h ' + minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's ';
                observable.next(countDown);

                // If the count down is finished, write some text
                if (distance < 0) {
                    clearInterval(x);
                    countDown = 'ALREADY EXPIRED';
                    observable.next(countDown);
            
                    //observable.complete();
                }
            }, 1000);

        });
      }
```

Below is the angular mat table in template

```
        <ng-container matColumnDef="timeLine">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Timeline </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let tasks"> 
                {{getTaskCountdown(tasks) | async}}
                <span>Task duration is {{taskDuration(tasks)}}</span>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Comment: please share the code link.. uploading in stackblitz if possible

Comment: I think your problem comes from having both a `setInterval` and an `async`. I would personally remove both and then use a [throttle decorator](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-useful-decorators-to-use-in-your-angular-projects-777e9b4c8c62) with a normal function, not an observable

Comment: @NirmalyaRoy just added a small code for both template and component on below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f3aeic?file=src/app/app.component.ts